# django-rest returning http 301 status code when calling http delete without trailing slash

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I recently experienced that on django rest framework a http 301 status code is returned when making a delete request, without including the trailing slash in the url when trailing_slash=True. While missing the trailing slash on a post request would return a runtime error. So my question is, is this a bug or is it expected behavior?

Comment: Normally, with REST APIs, the URL to a specific object **does not** have a trailing slash: **/objects/<id>** so that would be expected I'd say. PUT and DELETE are for specific objects and wouldn't require a trailing slash. A list of objects does have a trailing slash (**/objects/**) so a POST request to create a new object would require a trailing slash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 301 is expected because Django redirects you to the URL with the trailing slash since you have `trailing_slash=True`. See [APPEND_SLASH settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#append-slash) if you want to change that.